# With an array of int values, how to create a timer that counts down from each int value in the array? (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, timer, countdowntimer

The values in the array are placed by the user, so there could be any number of values in the array. If the first value in the array is 5, then the timer on the screen counts from 5 seconds to 0 seconds, then if the second value is 10, then the timer automatically starts counting down from 10 to 0 and stops if that is the last value in the array or continues if there are more.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to show some relevant code of your attempts at this so that we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have the code in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68685536/16421682. I feel it is not very helpful since the overall direction is probably wrong since I am new to using timers. So I am looking for other methods to solve this.

Comment: What's the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: I think the problem is that the timer begins at the end of the loop meaning that there is only a countdown for the last value in the array instead of every value. So I want the loop to only move to the next value in the array when the timer is finished counting down for the current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When solving this question, you need to identify the problem which is how do you **change which index should the timer take its timing from.**

```
import Foundation

var times = [10,20]

var index = 0

var time = times[index]

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: -1, repeats: true, block: { timer in
    
    print(time)
    
    time -= 1
    
    //reset only when it becomes -1 so you can see 0
    if time == -1 {
        
        if index < times.count - 1{
            //increase the index by 1; which is the next timing set
            
            index += 1
            
            time = times[index]
        } else {
            //invalidate if the index matches the number of count
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
})

timer.fire()
```

This listing shows how this problem is solved by **increasing the index by 1** every time it **reaches -1** *(so that it can show 0)* and setting the time to whatever the time is in that index.

Once the index is equals to the `(times.count - 1)`, the timer is **invalidated** because if it is equals to that then it will **fall out of range.**

Comment: Thank you. I tried this out and it works for every value in the array, however, the timer decrements too fast. How can I make it so variable time decrements by 1 every second because it seems like it is decrementing every millisecond or faster.

Comment: Nevermind I changed the withTimeInterval: -1 to withTimeInterval: 1 and it works fine now